# Swift 2 Conversion Hell Part 327: How to tame NSMatchingOptions being nil?

Tags: ios, regex, swift, macos

I have this method in a Regex class:

```
func test(input:String) -> Bool
{
    let matches = expression.matchesInString(input, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(input)))
    return matches.count > 0
}
```

Swift 2.1 tells me:

```
Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'NSMatchingOptions'
```

Can somebody tell me how to fix this properly? `NSMatchingOptions` doesn't seem to offer any default empty property.

Comment: Did you post the whole relevant code? Use `options: []` if you do not want to pass any options to the regex.

Comment: Empty array seems to work, too. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to pass any options to the regex, use `options: []`.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 2 an empty `OptionSetType` can be represented with `<Type>()`

```
NSMatchingOptions()
```

or just with a pair of square brackets

```
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSMatchingOptions` is an `enum`, not a class, so `nil` makes no sense. You have to use [one of the enum values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSMatchingOptions), the most likely of which is `Anchored`. It's really not a Swift issue at all.

Comment: `Anchored` will force the regex to try to match the whole string input. Is it what you need?

Comment: Since OP is specifying a range of the entire string's length, and wants the total number of matches, my guess is "yes".